# Python Inverted Circle (Turtle)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

[image]

How do you draw an inverted circle in Python using turtle only? i.e. a circle which is drawn clockwise rather than the traditional way of drawing one anticlockwise.

The current turtle is on the bottom of the vertically downwards line... How do I draw the indicated circle from there?

Comment: PLease show us the code you already have and what you tried yourself. SO is not a service that writes code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to your own question is incomplete.  You clearly stated in the problem:

> a circle which is drawn clockwise rather than the traditional way of
>   drawing one anticlockwise

So a better solution is:

```
x = turtle.Turtle()
x.right(90)
x.forward(100)
x.left(90)
x.circle(-100)
```

per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle):

> Draw the arc in counterclockwise direction if radius is positive,
>   otherwise in clockwise direction.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my example:

```py
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(100)
```

To draw a clockwise circle:

```py
t.circle(-100)
```

I hope that can help you.

Answer (score -1):

One way to draw a circle clockwise is to use this code.

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Pen()
bob.circle(-100)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
x=turtle.Turtle()
x.right(90)
x.forward(100)
x.right(90)
x.circle(100)
```